# XML merge nodes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have xml file like that:

```
<root>
 <scenario name="film1">
  <case name="aaa">
    <test name="test1">ok</test>
  </case>
  <case name="bbb">
    <test name="test2">not ok</test>
  </case>
  <case name="aaa">
    <test name="test3">not ok</test>
  </case>
  <case name="bbb">
    <test name="test66">ok</test>
  </case>
 </scenario>
</root>
```

Of course there is more nodes like scenario but i want group `case` for each scenario.
I expect something like that:

```
<root>
 <scenario name="fil1">
  <case name="aaa">
    <test name="test1">ok</test>
    <test name="test3">not ok</test>
  </case>
   <case name="bbb">
    <test name="test2">not ok</test>
    <test name="test66">ok</test>
  </case>
 </scenario>
</root>
```

I made xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="scenario">
    <scenario>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </scenario>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match ="case">
    <case>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </case>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DO you know what i should do now?

Comment: What you are looking for is grouping in XSLT. Have a look into muenchian grouping

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is allowed?

Comment: no it is not allowed :( I dont get this muenchian grouping...

Comment: "*I dont get this muenchian grouping...*" What kind of an answer do you expect, then? There's [an excellent article explaining the method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), and countless examples of implementation here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in your question you want to group `case` for each `scenario`. If you do have multiple `scenario` elements, and want to group the `case` elements within each such element, you would need to make use of a concatenated key:

```
<xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="concat(../@name, '|', @name)" />
```

This means if you had two `case` elements with the same `name`, but in different `scenario` elements, then they would still be grouped separately.

Now, for the grouping, for each `case` statement within a `scenario`, you need to find the `case` elements that occur first in the key for its given attributes. This can be done as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="case[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))[1])]" />
```

To break it down...

`key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))` - Gets all elements with the same attributes

`key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))[1]` - Gets the first element of that list

`generate-id(key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))[1])` - Generates the unique id for that first element, so it can be compared with the current element.

So, effectively, you get the distinct elements. You can then get the items in the "group" using the key again

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="concat(../@name, '|', @name)" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scenario">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="case[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))[1])]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match ="case">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('case', concat(../@name, '|', @name))">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As mentioned in comments, the definitive article on this approach can be found at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html, so it is worth reading it, and re-reading it, then practising it, until you finally understand it.

Also, note the use of the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which means you don't have to write a template for each specific element if all you do is want to copy it without changes.

Comment: I did solution using Python. But your post make me so happy because someone explain me a little.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="scenario">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="case">
    <xsl:param name="thisName">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test=".=/root/scenario/case[@name=$thisName][1]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/scenario/case[@name=$thisName]/test" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="@*">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution - read here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -- You could also roll several of your templates into one - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT_2

Comment: Throw him a frickin bone. You can see from his XSLT that he is learning.

Answer (score 0):

Standard approach in xslt 1.0 - muenchian grouping.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="case-by-name" match="case" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:key name="test-by-case" match="test" use="parent::*/@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scenario">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- process only first cases in groups -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="case[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case-by-name', @name)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="case">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- copy all tests for corresponding case name -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('test-by-case', @name)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The second key is redundant: just use `<xsl:copy-of select="key('case-by-name', @name)/test"/>`